# ¿como puedo sumar los enter que presione como un contador en java?

Tags: java

Un cordial salud soy novato en el tema de la programación en java , me gustaría saber como puedo hacer una especie de contador en java para que cada vez que presione enter me sume para poderlo comparar y después de cierta cantidad de enter mostrar un mensaje con gráficos en movimiento

gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow, da un [tour] y revisa [ask] para que puedas formular una pregunta que sea aceptada por la comunidad. Muestra lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 0):

En java tienes que implementar un Event Listering de tipo formKeyPressed, este tipo de eventos se implementan en el constructor del Jframe donde el usuario va a pulsar la tecla, la libreria que utiliza dicho evento es **java.awt.event.KeyEvent** con ella solo queda agregar el metodo que corresponde al listering de la siguiente forma

```
 private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        char dato = evt.getKeyChar();
       } 
    }//GEN-LAST:event_formKeyPressed
```

Teniendo en cuenta que el event debe estar situado y debe trabajar de la mano con el JFrame que muestra la imagen.